# Trying to get my apache container to respond to localhost:8080

Tags: docker

I have a bunch of containers running on my ubuntu laptop.As you can see below, I should be able to type in localhost:8080 in the browser and get some response. Instead I get

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any idea why?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
143fbe3867e3        richb201/apache-with-code:latest   "/app-entrypoint.sh …"   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 8443/tcp   sub_crud_webserver_1
0c2048ef273e        bitnami/mariadb:latest             "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         3306/tcp                                     sub_crud_mariadb_1
fb30f99f037b        bitnami/php-fpm:latest             "php-fpm -F --pid /o…"   2 days ago          Up 19 hours         9000/tcp                                     html_php-fpm_1
be5155202f43        bitnami/mariadb:latest             "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   2 days ago          Up 19 hours         3306/tcp                                     html_mariadb_1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    image: richb201/apache-with-code:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - /sub_crud:/var/www/html/sub_crud
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host='richb201-XPS-13-9370'

  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/bitnami

  php-fpm:
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:latest
    volumes:
      - /sub_crud:/var/www/html/sub_crud
    volumes:
```

Comment: Same problem for localhost:8000

Comment: Have you checked whether the underlying container is running on port 8080?

Answer (score 2):

According to your docker-compose that you mentioned in a comment (better put this into your question though) you map port 8000 to port 8000. Hence, any requests going to port 8000 on your local machine are received from port 8000 within your container.

If you want to use port 8080 you have to adapt the docker-compose file accordingly, i.e., `8080:8080`. Note here that I assume that the apache server in your `richb201/apache-with-code` image is running on port 8080.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it is running on port 8080, but I probably need to review the underlying container to be sure. I only added my code to it in a layer.

Comment: This is what I see in the container inspect:           "PortBindings": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8000"
                    }
                ]
            },